# Save an entire webpage, with all images and css, into just one folder and one file, with wget?

Tags: browser, wget, css, webpage, save-as

Is there a way to mimic the "Save - as" function in a browser with wget?

When I save a webpage in a browser, I get a folder with the assets(images, js, css) and the index file, which has the page name:

```
Nov 28 reddit: the front page of the internet_files
Nov 28 reddit: the front page of the internet.html
```

But no matter what, when I use wget, I get something like this:

```
Nov 28  a.thumbs.redditmedia.com
Nov 28  b.thumbs.redditmedia.com
Nov 28  m.reddit.com
Nov 28  out.reddit.com
Nov 28  reddit.com
Nov 28  www.reddit.com
Nov 28  www.redditstatic.com
```

I tried using these:

`wget -E -H -k -K -p https://reddit.com`
`wget -r -x -mirror https://reddit.com`

and came up with this:
`wget -E -H -k -p -e robots=off https://www.reddit.com`

but all of them either made several folders or didn't download everything needed to view the page offline.

How would I set this up?

Answer (score 0):

You/WGET can't. It can download all linked resources in one given download, but that would result in multiple folders due to its nature of crawling, not interpreting (and not being bound to HTTP either).

Also your impression is too narrow: there are web browsers which can save pages into MHT files/archives, which is even a standard - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML